# How to make newly added element to render in multiline webix datatable cell?

Tags: datatable, multiline, webix

My webix datatable has a editable cell which show texts in multiline. However, if I am adding a new element to the cell, it is not getting shown in the cell. Nevertheless the tooltip shows the new element got added to it.

Below is my snippet in which the last column (Message) is editable and multi-line:
Snippet: https://snippet.webix.com/xdvi4fek

How can I make cell height longer or what is the way to make it visible after adding ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Webix Datatable doesn't have a real "cell auto-height mode". There is a adjustRowHeight API which sets height of rows, so they will fit all the data. You need to call it from onAfterEditStop event.

```
on:{
onAfterEditStop:function(){
  this.adjustRowHeight("id2");
},
```

Also, be sure to set

```
fixedRowHeight:false,
```

in datatables' configuration

Here is the updated snippet - https://snippet.webix.com/eidtg9sa